# Error at trying to measure faster with SCPI

Tags: python, triggers, pyvisa

I am trying to measure the Current with the Keysight 34461A DMM over pyvisa with SCPI.
I am currently using this code:

```
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
print("Resources detected\n{}\n".format(rm.list_resources()))

dmm = rm.open_resource('USB0::0x2A8D::0x1301::MY60042144::INSTR')
print(dmm.query("*IDN?"))


dmm.write('CONF:CURR:DC AUTO')
dmm.write('SAMP:COUN 4')
dmm.write('TRIG:COUN 1')
print(dmm.query('READ?'))
```

With this code I get 4 Measurements. But I need much more. If I change the 'SAMP:COUN 4' oder 'TRIG:COUN 1' to more than 4 or more than 1 i get this error: "pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed."

Does someone knows the problem or knows how i can measure many many currents in one second in another way?

Thanks alot!